# Testing for ODR image resources in main bundle

Tags: swift, bundle, xctest, xctestcase

I'm trying to write a test to make sure all ODR images are available in the main bundle:

```
let testBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self)) //This is probably wrong... I'm trying to test the main bundle.

for cat in cats {
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: cat.image)
    let fileNameWithoutExtension = fileURL.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
    let fileExtension = fileURL.pathExtension
    let fileUrl = testBundle.url(forResource: fileNameWithoutExtension, withExtension: fileExtension)
   // let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileNameWithoutExtension, withExtension: fileExtension) // also doesn't work
    XCTAssertNotNil(fileUrl, "File \(cat.image) is not available as an ODR resource.")
}
```

`cat.image` could be "filename.jpg" or "filename.png" for example.

But this test fails for every image, even those that I'm sure are present in the bundle. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you testing the test bundle?

Comment: `let fileUrl = testBundle.url(forResource: fileNameWithoutExtension, withExtension: fileExtension)`

Comment: Then you should perhaps change the title of the question and I must say I don't really see the point of this.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm trying to test if the files are in the main bundle, yes. How can I do that? This doesn't work either: `let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileNameWithoutExtension, withExtension: fileExtension)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this is to try to convert the name of all the images you created to a UIImage, if you can all the Assets are imported correctly.

I added cat 1, 2 and 3 in assets and made this code for testing if they exist:

```
let testBundle = Bundle(for: pergunta_stackTests.self)

let cats: [Cats] = [Cats(name: "James", image: "cat1.jpeg"),
Cats(name: "Luke", image: "cat2.jpeg"),
Cats(name: "Amir", image: "cat3.jpeg")]

func testIfCatsExist() {
    for cat in cats {
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: cat.image)
        let fileNameWithoutExtension = fileURL.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
        let imageCreate = UIImage(named: fileNameWithoutExtension)
        XCTAssertNotNil(imageCreate, "File \(cat.image) is not available as an ODR resource.")
    }
}
```

If there are any nuances that I didn't notice, let me know ;)

Comment: This fails as well. I don't think `UIImage(named: fileNameWithoutExtension)` works without the file extension.

Comment: just using `let image = UIImage(named: cat.image)` fails as well

Comment: Try to see if the image itself, in the assets is checked for your test module.